# How to store multiple values into a variable in MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has business_id,business_name,business_points and so on.
I have to create a procedure to do some mathematical calculation on business_points.When i call the procedure the procedure should automatically get all the business_id and run calculations on that.
Now the issue is that if i do

```
set @businessid=select business_id from businessmaters;
```

I will only get the last business_id inside the variable.
And I cant use count because business_id are not sequential.

What do i have to do so that i can store all the business_id in a variable.
Is there a way i can implement array in mysql.

Comment: AFAIK the only array-like thing is a temp table.

Comment: Usually you let databases do calculations for a set of rows. Most times joins or subselects will do that. Or a temp table, as @Vatev mentioned. If this should not be possible, you could use a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html). Many people consider the use of cursors as harmful.

Comment: the only way to get it all into a variable is to do a GROUP_CONCAT() which will get your data in there... but thats a comma separated string.. you could parse it out after getting it in the variable.. but that might be a bit of work.